# PySimpleGUI Menubar is not displayed

Tags: python, pysimplegui, menubar

I'm learning PySimpleGUI.
The code below comes from a tutorial on Menubar item.
When I run it on my Mac PC, there is NO menu bar appearing on the screen.
Initially I thought it was a coding problem but after trying on other codes on Menubar, nothing worked on my PC.

I tried to uninstall/re-install, upgrade the package, recreate project folder etc... nothing worked so far.

Then I realised that the main menu itself doesn't have menubar appearing where it should be as a default (screenshot attached)

I'm working on PyCharm/MacOS(Ventura 13.4.1)

[PySimpleGUI main/start menu screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw9ZJ.jpg)

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

menu_def = [['File', ['New', 'Open', 'Save', 'Exit']],
            ['Edit', ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'Undo']],
            ['Help', 'About...']]

layout = [[sg.Menu(menu_def)],
          [sg.Multiline("", key='-IN-',
                        expand_x=True, expand_y=True)],
          [sg.Multiline("", key='-OUT-',
                        expand_x=True, expand_y=True)],
          [sg.Text("", key='-TXT-',
                   expand_x=True, font=('Arial Bold', 14))]
]

window = sg.Window('Menu', layout, size=(715, 300))

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)

    if event != sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        window['-TXT-'].update(values[0] + "Menu Button Clicked")
    if event == 'Copy':
        txt = window['-IN-'].get()
    if event == 'Paste':
        window['-OUT-'].update(value=window['-IN-'].get())
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

- Rewrite code
- Re-install package
- Upgrade package
- Recreate project folder

So far nothing worked.

Comment: The Mac's menubar is located elsewhere on the screen. Apple's support documentation reads "The menu bar runs along the top of the screen on your Mac. "  The Mac's user interface works differently than Windows & Linux, not just for PySimpleGUI, but all programs as far as I know.

Comment: @MikefromPSG Thank you! My bad, I was staring at the widget's window and never thought of looking elsewhere.

Comment: You can use a `MenubarCustom` element if you really want one on your window.